# Why won't data entered into CiviCRM profile html snippet save?

Tags: profile, form-snippets

I'm using Joomla 3.4.1 with CiviCRM 4.6.3 on a [demo site](http://tremololabs.com/clients/IREHRTEST/) as part of a re-design. I've used the CiviCRM profiles html snippet to create a Joomla signup module. [See here for example](http://tremololabs.com/clients/IREHRTEST/issues/international-dimensions/434-russia-s-international-conservative-forum-draws-american-white-nationalists).

It worked once - storing the name and email into CiviCRM and even re-directing to the proper page and giving a thank you message after it stored the data.

However, now when you hit "save" in the module, this time nothing is saved and it kicks you back to the front page. I've read the manual, searched the forums, and tried a bunch of stuff, but nothing works. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tested by submitting just the profile in either create or edit mode? Does that work?

Comment: Yes. Works in Use Profile Create mode. But that takes you to it's own page, doesn't use as module.

Comment: Have u checked the civicrm error log and see if any errors are recorded when you do the above

Comment: and if you just put the html snippet for the profile in a 'page' does that work?

Comment: Nothing in the log. And the snippet into a 'page' doesn't work.

Comment: is this the path to the base profile, or something you or joomla cook up? http://tremololabs.com/clients/IREHRTEST/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&gid=14&reset=1 and if it is, does it work as expected?

Comment: when i submit from that page i end up here - http://tremololabs.com/clients/IREHRTEST/donate - if i fill that in i don't get the expected outcome but this is me just being nosy in case something springs to mind - don't feel like i am being much help though

Comment: 1. So I just want to verify your expectations and what is happening. Re-entering the SAME information into the form is NOT supposed to create an additional contact. Try entering different information and see if a contact is created. 2. Being sent to the homepage suggests there was a severe error on the server when processing the page OR that the redirect afterwards didn't work (possibly because something changed after it was working). Do you have any custom code doing things like creating Joomla! users? If you have modified any of the Advanced Settings for the profile, maybe reset them.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Joomla 2 and CiviCRM 4.63.  I can reliably make it not work, redirecting to the front page and not storing the entered data, by starting a fresh browser session and filling in the form.

Comment: I can reliably make it work by first submitting a form via the direct link to the profile.  After that, the page with HTML snippet embedded does work.

When it doesn't work, I get error messages in apache's error.log: 3 instances of 

access_compat:error] [pid 2251] [client 127.0.0.1:52344] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/media/civicrm/

The three files are:

ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.4ad448907e04b5810b883636d637148f.log
upload/delete-this-2zz8zIx8h2
custom/delete-this-WAZfeHHlJS

Comment: Correction to my last  comment: to make the embedded HTML snippet work in a new browser session, I need merely load the direct profile - I don't even need to fill it out.  Then submitting the snippet works properly.  I examined cookies and didn't see any changes on the client side.  Maybe something is being set on the server side?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?  Devin, similar to my scenario, if I try to fill out your embedded form I get kicked to the front page.  But if I first load http://tremololabs.com/clients/IREHRTEST/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&gid=15&reset=1 then I can submit your embedded form.

Comment: More troubleshooting: if I get the embedded form working by loading the Profile version, then delete the cookies from my browser, I can make the embedded form break again.  And although I've been testing with a Private Window in Opera (based on Chrome engine), I've noticed that the same cookie name/value pairs exist across multiple browser windows.  If I break the embedded form in one private window, then load a Profile in another private window, the embedded form works again.  So there's something going on server-side, maybe with the cookies?  I'm going to ask a new question about that.

Comment: More interesting tidbits: when I load a Profile in another Private Window to make the embedded version work, it doesn't matter if the Profile is the same one.  That is, I'm working with an embedded version of Form gid #14, but loading the Profile for gid #17 allows the embedded form to work.  Also, restarting apache does not break the embedded form if it's in a working state - which I think means CiviCRM is not relying on session data (which would be lost on server restart), but on the cookies.  I could well be confused about this, though.

Comment: Hideous hack that makes it work for me: include an <iframe> of any Profile, and hide the iframe with CSS display: none.  Now the embedded form seems to work correctly, since the browser is loading the Profile version and setting whatever magical thing allows the embedded form to submit properly.  I'm not proud of it, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for that, Norris! I'd prefer, however, not to rely on a hack (as awesome as it is), for fear of problems down the road. So still very much need help on this one.

Comment: Devin, can you confirm whether you have the same pattern as I see?  Submitting the form from a fresh browser session fails, but loading a Profile page, then submitting the form, makes it work?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it's the recaptcha on the form action page?

http://tremololabs.com/clients/IREHRTEST/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&gid=15&reset=1

My guess is that posting to that page without the recaptcha data (which is what your form does) is going to cause the server to be annoyed, and perhaps there's some kind of code or server security something that is hiding the response and just sending the user to the front page of your site? Do you have some kind of special configuration for your recaptcha perhaps?

Comment: Great find.i had taken Look at the profile page and did not make that connection

Comment: I was having this problem before I turned recaptcha on. But I went ahead and turned off recaptcha. Now the module works *sometimes*, other times it does the same thing - no save and kick back to the frontpage.

Comment: From the Error Log - May 29 23:41:35  [info] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(363): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(362): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer")

Comment: #2 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1247): CRM_Utils_Type::validate(NULL, "Integer")
#3 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1166): CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery("\nSELECT module,is_reserved\n  FROM civicrm_uf_group\n  LEFT JOIN civicrm_uf_...", (Array:1), TRUE)

Comment: #4 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Form/Edit.php(122): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\nSELECT module,is_reserved\n  FROM civicrm_uf_group\n  LEFT JOIN civicrm_uf_...", (Array:1))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Profile_Form_Edit->preProcess()

Comment: #6 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Profile_Form_Edit), "display")

Comment: #8 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Profile_Form_Edit), "display")
#9 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")

Comment: #10 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(115): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Router.php(118): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Profile_Form_Edit", "Create Profile", (Array:2))

Comment: #12 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Profile_Page_Router->run((Array:3), NULL)
#13 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#14 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

Comment: #15 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#16 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(391): require_once("/var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/components/com_civ...")

Comment: #18 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(371): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/components/com_civ...")
#19 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#20 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()

Comment: #21 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(252): JApplicationSite->doExecute()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/tremololabs.com/httpdocs/clients/IREHRTEST/index.php(40): JApplicationCms->execute()
#23 {main}

Comment: This error is from May 29...are you sure it's related?  Do you get similar errors when it fails now?

Comment: Yes, same error. It's on a test site so not much traffic. And haven't worked on it since this error ruined my week. Happy to post the latest if it'll help, but it looks about the same.

Comment: It might be more legible if you post it as a [gist](https://gist.github.com) next time. (Make your situation easier to read, and you'll increase the chances of someone making the effort to absorb it.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've tracked down the problem on my site to the uk.co.vedaconsulting Mailchimp plugin.  Removing that seems to fix my issue on my test server, making my hack of embedding an iframe unnecessary.  Hopefully it also fixes my timeout problem described at [How do I make profile submissions more reliable, or at least not silently fail?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/how-do-i-make-profile-submissions-more-reliable-or-at-least-not-silently-fail)

I need to confirm that this fixes the problem on our production server.

Devin, are you using the Mailchimp extension?  Or any others you can try disabling?

Comment: Nope, i was wrong...misled by confusions in reloading pages and accidentally making it work with the background-loaded embedded form hack.  Disabling Mailchimp or other plugins does not in fact change anything.  See my other question for the workaround hack I've settled on.